# docker-compose up is failing to start one of the container service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have defined 3 services in the docker-compose.yaml file. Out of which 2 services (my-app_my-app_1 & my-app_mongodb_1) are getting started automatically when firing this command `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yaml up`. But failing to start one of the service (my-app_mongo-express_1). Just to add, I can start the failed container successfully again by executing `docker start my-app_mongo-express_1` separately.

**Contents of file - docker-compose.yaml:**

```
→ cat docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'
services:
  my-app:
    image: maryo/my-app:1.2
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    volumes:
      - mongo-data:/data/db
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 8080:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=password
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
volumes:
  mongo-data:
    driver: local
```

**Output of `docker-compose ps`**

```
→ docker-compose ps
NAME                     COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
my-app_mongo-express_1   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   mongo-express       exited (0)
my-app_mongodb_1         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   mongodb             running             0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp
my-app_my-app_1          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   my-app              running             0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp
```

**Docker logs for mongo-express container:**

```
→ docker logs my-app_mongo-express_1
Welcome to mongo-express
------------------------


(node:8) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
Could not connect to database using connectionString: mongodb://admin:password@mongodb:27017/"
(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.25.0.4:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError'
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:441:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:564:14
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1000:11
    at /node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:32:7
    at callback (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:289:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:319:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:421:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
(node:8) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Works fine if I start that container separately:**

```
→ docker start my-app_mongo-express_1
my-app_mongo-express_1


→ docker-compose ps
NAME                     COMMAND                  SERVICE             STATUS              PORTS
my-app_mongo-express_1   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   mongo-express       running             0.0.0.0:8080->8081/tcp, :::8080->8081/tcp
my-app_mongodb_1         "docker-entrypoint.s…"   mongodb             running             0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp
my-app_my-app_1          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   my-app              running             0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp
```

What am I missing? Why I am not able to start all the containers together using `docker-compose up`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) option to control the order in which your defined services startup.

In this specific case, the `mongo-express` service has a dependency on the `mongodb` service, and so if the `mongo-express` service is started before `mongodb`, it will fail to connect:

```
Could not connect to database using connectionString
```

This is why starting the `mongo-express` service manually succeeds (because `mongodb` is already running). However, note the following caveat from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) which you may still need to address:

> However, for startup Compose does not wait until a container is “ready” (whatever that means for your particular application) - only until it’s running . . . To handle this, design your application to attempt to re-establish a connection to the database after a failure. If the application retries the connection, it can eventually connect to the database.